# How to make a drop down menu in HTML display multiple images?

Tags: javascript, html

I want each selection on a drop down menu to display multiple things. If sensor 1 is selected, a picture of the location of sensor 1 and the address of sensor 1 needs to be displayed. I don't know how to add multiple functions to the drop down menu selections so I have tried making the address an image and trying to display multiple images with a single selection. The same goes for sensor 2 and sensor 3 but let's just work with sensor 1.

```
 <select onchange="$('#imageToSwap').attr('src', this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);$('#imageToSwap2').attr('src', this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
<option value="https://i.imgur.com/KxkwWjO.png" value="https://i.imgur.com/L8fx0iM.png"  selected>Sensor 1</option>
<option value="https://i.imgur.com/DjIuGQ0.png">Sensor 2</option>
<option value="https://i.imgur.com/IZ7FoQN.png">Sensor 3</option>
</select><img id="imageToSwap" class="profile" src="https://i.imgur.com/KxkwWjO.png"><img id="imageToSwap2" class="profile" src="https://i.imgur.com/L8fx0iM.png">
```

Comment: If you are hard coding in a bunch of images, and want the image displayed to be dependent on what's selected, you should just modify the classes for the different elements to set the visibility of the images.

This isn't pure JS/HTML, you should add a tag for what framework/technology your using to do inline manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

Y can't you do something like this?

```
<img id="img" src=''/>
<p>Select a new car from the list.</p>

<select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
  <option value="Audi">Audi</option>
  <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
  <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="Volvo">Volvo</option>
</select>

<p>When you select a new car, a function is triggered which outputs the value of the selected car.</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You selected: " + x;
  document.getElementById("img").src='pic_bulboff.gif'
}
</script>
```

Comment: When you select sensor 1, I want the image of the location of sensor 1 to appear, but along with that I want the address to appear too. The two things need to be tied together. Each sensor will have a different address.

Comment: Are these image and address hardcoded? Meaning if you know which address and image has to be displayed for which sensor. in the onChange function you can get the image and address for that selected sensor and set the img and the <p> tag appropriately